# GVIM Vundle issue on windows

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vundle

I'm getting this error with Vundle `begin` method.

```
Error detected while processing function vundle#end..vundle#config#activ
ate_bundles..<SNR>4_rtp_add_a:

line    4:

E117: Unknown function: fnameescape

E15: Invalid expression: 'set rtp^='.fnameescape(prepends)

line    5:

E117: Unknown function: fnameescape

E15: Invalid expression: 'set rtp+='.fnameescape(appends)

Error detected while processing function vundle#end..vundle#config#activ
ate_bundles..<SNR>4_rtp_add_defaults:

line    7:

E117: Unknown function: fnameescape

E15: Invalid expression: fnameescape(default_rtp_items[0])

line    8:

E121: Undefined variable: first_item

E15: Invalid expression: 'set rtp-=' . first_item

line    9:

E121: Undefined variable: first_item

E15: Invalid expression: 'set rtp^=' . first_item

Error detected while processing D:\GVimPortable\Data\settings\vimrc:

line  117:

E518: Unknown option: relativenumber

line  357:

E185: Cannot find color scheme solarized
```

I've used Vundle with MAC before, but in windows it's not working.
Not sure it's with windows specific or not.
Please help if you have any idea about this issue.
Thanks

Comment: what vim version is this?

Answer (score 1):

Your Vim doesn't have the `fnameescape()` function, nor `'relativenumber'`. It must be a really old Vim version, like 7.0 or 7.1. You can check with `:version`.

To use Vundle, you need to upgrade to a newer version; i.e. 7.4 or 8.0.